# Eclipse imported jar package, but start Tomcat or that cannot find class

Tags: java, tomcat, mybatis

I have imported the jar package

[image]

but start Tomcat or that cannot find class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to add jar in your classpath.

1. left click on project go into configure build path.
2. click on add external jar select particular jar and add it and click on apply.
3. after applying refresh project an restart server and again deploy project on server.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the jar file has been deploy to the war WEB-INF/lib directory?